# Android error inflating class on xml

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, view, custom-controls

I created a class where extends from ViewFlipper. When I try to instantiate on xml, it gives me this "error inflating class on xml"

FixedViewFlipper

```
public FixedViewFlipper(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public FixedViewFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Xml

```
<View class="com.touchcare.idealogix.android.FixedViewFlipper"
    android:id="@+id/flipperAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >
</View>
```

[Logcat](http://pastebin.com/hYmrD0sp)

EDIT: I am using TabActivity at my MainActivity.

Comment: is your FixedViewFlipper class in that package that you specify in your view class xml?? im sorry but thats all I could guess from your code/logcat

Comment: `package touchcare.idealogix.android;`

`public class FixedViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper`

Comment: so you don't need the "com" on the beginning of your class definition in the xml

Comment: @L7ColWinters is right, but if that doesnt solve the issue try adding the other constructor like:
`public FixedViewFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle) { //something}`

Comment: @Raykud I took a look at it but it seems that there is no defStyle for ViewFlipper, only Context and Context, AttributeSet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need view to not be capitalized -

```
<view 
    class="touchcare.idealogix.android.FixedViewFlipper"
    android:id="@+id/flipperAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >
</view>
```

It's perfectly valid syntax and is how its done in a lot of the google apps

Comment: Eclipse autocomplete method says is fine with capitals :S

Comment: Still giving me the exception.

Comment: @Raykud eclipse autocomplete is pointing you to `<View/>`, which refers to the Android class `View`.  the `<view class=""/>` syntax points to a custom view of type class.  Really `<View />` is shorthand for `<view class="com.android.view.View"/>`

Comment: oh, thanks for the info. I was in doubt since I remember I had this issue before and fixed it with underscore V but was wondering why eclipse was setting me upper.

Comment: this was helpful to me, I didn't know you specify the nodes class like this.

Comment: @GabrielCasado Are you still getting the exception when you fix your package or something else now?

Comment: Still getting the exception. The purpose of this FixedViewFlipper was to avoid the bug in 2.1 android where when you rotate the device fast enough, the app crashes. So I though this was going to be an easier solution, that's why I tried this FixedViewFlipper approach. Maybe I should add a delay to rotation to fix this...